# Connection error MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I copied this from W3Schools and when I try to run it it gives me the a error. I am really new to MySQL so I am trying to fix this but I don't know how.

ERROR:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Informatica\test.php on line 10 Connection failed:
>   Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error means the password you have used for the `username` user is incorrect. ;)

Comment: Your password is invalid

Comment: If you just set up a LAMP/WAMP environment you probably would have `root` for both username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your username or password is incorrect if you are very new and just starting with the local server try

$username = "root";

$password = "";

as your username and password

Answer (score 2):

W3schools don't know your localhost details, do the following

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; //put your username here
$password = "";   // your password here
```

Leave password empty and put "root" in username, that's the default xampp setting.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add correct information provided by your hosting provider here :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

//Connection to mysql check

```
if(! $conn ) {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
         }

mysqli_select_db($conn,'databaseName');

?>
```

Comment: add an explanation of your code what you did, & try not to post similar or exact answers,